# Existence of $p \times p $ matrices $A$ and $B$ over the field $\mathbb F_p$, $p$ prime, such that $AB-BA=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $p$  be a prime number. Prove or disprove that there exists $p\times p$ matrices $A$ and $B$ over a field $\mathbb F_p$ with $AB-BA = I$.

With the aid of MAPLE i was able to find out that this statement is valid for $2$ and $3$. But hadn't been able to prove it theoretically. 
This is a homework question and we would receive extra marks if solved. Any hint(s) will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125219/traceless-matrices-and-commutators The answer is YES, but I don't know the proof, and it's not straightforward (at least the original proof isn't).

Comment: If you read my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99175/solutions-to-the-matrix-equation-mathbfab-ba-i-over-general-fields/99461#99461 you can probably build examples by hand (and all of them, in fact)

Comment: How is it possibile?! tr(AB-BA)=0 .

Comment: @Ivan, $\mathrm{tr}(I)=p\cdot 1=0\pmod p$.

Comment: lol, I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to generate such matrices, by starting from infinite-dimensional spaces.

Let $k$ be a field and consider the vector space $ V = k[x]$ of polynomials in one variable over $k$.

We have two nice linear maps from $V$ to itself, namely $D: V\to V$ which is differentiation, and $M:V\to V$ which is multiplication by $x$.

Now we note that $DM - MD$ is the identity on $V$, so we now have our example when working in an infinite-dimensional space.

To get an example in case $k$ has characteristic $p$ and the space has dimension divisible by $p$ (i.e. we want $np\times np$ matrices $A$ and $B$ for some $n$ such that $AB - BA = I$), we note that the subspace $W$ of polynomials divisible by $x^p$ is invariant under both $D$ and $M$ (for $M$ this is obvious and for $D$ this is because we are in characteristic $p$, so $D(x^p) = 0$).

Thus, on the quotient $V/W$ we get linear maps $\overline{D}$ and $\overline{M}$, which precisely satisfy that $\overline{D}\overline{M} - \overline{M}\overline{D} = I$ as we wanted.

This gives us $p\times p$ matrices. To get $np\times np$ matrices, we simply put $n$ copies of these matrices into the diagonal.

I leave it as an exercise for the interested reader to actually write up the matrices found in this way.