# Can we write a matrix with zero trace as a commutator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $F$ be a field, with $\text{char}(F) = 0$, and $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$ with $\text{tr}(A) = 0$. Show that there are matrices $B,C \in M_{n\times n}(F)$ that $A = BC - CB$.

Comment: One nice proof is presented [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf)

Comment: It also follows from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769881/is-every-element-of-a-complex-semisimple-lie-algebra-a-commutator), for the simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ of traceless matrices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traceless matrices and commutators](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125219/traceless-matrices-and-commutators)