# Characterizing the image of the commutator

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, reference-request

The [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory) of square matrices,
$$[A,B]:=AB - BA,$$
can be viewed as a function $[\cdot,\cdot]:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (or $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$) that takes two matrices as input and returns a matrix as output.

**Questions:**

- What is known about the image of this function?
- What matrices are in the image, and what algebraic and topological structures does the image have?

Stated another way, what are the characteristics of the set of matrices $M$ that can be written in the form $M=AB-BA$ for some $A,B$?

Clearly, a necessary condition is that the trace of a matrix in the image of the commutator must be zero, since $\text{trace}(AB)=\text{trace}(BA)$. However, it is not clear (to me) whether this condition is sufficient to characterize the set (I suspect it is not).

---

Much information can be found online about the image of the [group-theoretic commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup), but I am interested in the ring-theoretic commutator, which is different, and in particular, I am interested in the special case where the commutator is applied to square matrices that are real or complex valued.

Comment: [Maybe duplicate?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125219/traceless-matrices-and-commutators?rq=1)

Comment: Notice that anything in the image has trace zero. I'm pretty sure that any traceless matrix is in the image too, but don't have time for a proof at the moment.

Comment: Apparently the answer is that it is precisely the traceless matrices, although the argument's a bit tricky (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/252324/232). A more natural question is about linear combinations of commutators; this always forms a Lie subalgebra, for example, and has other nice properties.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. Since it turns out that all traceless matrices are commutators (which I did not expect a priori), the answer to that question by user1551 also answers this question. However, what is there to be gained by taking linear combinations of commutators, if they already form a linear subspace by themselves?

Comment: @Nick: I mean to say that it's always true that if $A$ is a $k$-algebra, then $k$-linear combinations of commutators of $A$ is a Lie $k$-subalgebra of $A$, usually denoted $[A, A]$. It shouldn't be true in general that every element of $[A, A]$ is a commutator, even if it's true in this case; I don't know a counterexample though. The quotient $A/[A, A]$ is called the zeroth Hochschild homology $HH_0(A)$ and is a natural object of study for several reasons. it turns out, for example, to be invariant under Morita equivalence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that every matrix with zero trace can also be written as a commutator, so the image of the commutator is exactly the set of traceless matrices. See, for example, the excellent answer here by user1551:
[Does the set of matrix commutators form a subspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95537/does-the-set-of-matrix-commutators-form-a-subspace/252324#252324)

Also, thanks to Qiaochu Yuan for pointing out this link in the comments.