# is it possible to find such nonsingular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular matrices in $End(V)$ (the space of endomoprhisms for an n-dimensional vector space $V$, hence a space of nonsingular matrices).  Let $[A, B] = AB - BA$.  Is it possible to find matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $[A, B] = AB - BA = E_{ij}$ where $i \neq j$?  I other words, is it possible to find such matrices so that $[A, B]$ is a matrix with zeros everywhere except in the $ij$-th position for $i \neq j$?

Comment: Try two nonsingular symmetric matrices which do not commute.

Comment: @jynan:  the result will be skew-symmetric.

Comment: Doesn't it satisy the OP's requirement? It has zero in diagonals. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @jnyan If $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular noncommuting symmetric matrices then $[A,B]$ will be skew-symmetric. The OP asked for $[A,B] = E_{ij}$ which is not skew-symmetric. As explained in the question $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with zeros everywhere except in the $ij$'th position. That is not skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Does the set of matrix commutators form a subspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95537/does-the-set-of-matrix-commutators-form-a-subspace) and [Traceless matrices and commutators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125219/traceless-matrices-and-commutators).

Here is an answer using the idea from the first of those links. Let $A$ be a diagonal matrix with distinct, nonzero diagonal entries $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$. Let $B = A + E_{ij}/(a_i-a_j)$. Then $A$ is invertible because it is diagonal with nonzero diagonal entries, and $B$ is invertible because it is upper or lower triangular with nonzero diagonal entries; and we have that
$$
\begin{split}
  AB-BA &= A(A+E_{ij}/(a_i-a_j))-(A+E_{ij}/(a_i-a_j))A \\
   &= (AE_{ij}-E_{ij}A)/(a_i-a_j) \\
   &= (a_i E_{ij} - E_{ij} a_j)/(a_i-a_j) \\
   &= E_{ij} ,
\end{split}
$$
as desired.